# Open in new window link in an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an iframe on a page and there is a link (on the same domain) I would like to open in a new physical window. When I use target="_blank", it just reloads the page in an iframe with the new one.

I also tried this JavaScript/jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[target=_blank]').click(function() {
        window.open(this.href);
        return false;
    })
});
```

With no success.

The HTML tag looks like this:

```
<a class="blue" href="/page/terms-of-service" target="_blank">Terms of Service</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try something like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(window).load(function() {
        $('iframe').contents().find('body a.blue').click(function() {
            window.open(this.href);
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If your link really looks like this:

```
<a href="blah" target="_blank">some text</a>
```

...then barring something *very unusual*, any [conforming browser](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/types.html#type-frame-target) will open the linked page in a new window (or new tab, on tabbed browsers with the "new window = new tab" feature turned on). If that's not happening, there's something specific to your page that's interfering with the normal process. If you post the actual link markup, we may be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

Try putting `<base target="_blank" />` into the `<head>` tag of the iframe page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
window.parent.location = 'http://www.yourSite.com/mypage';
```