# How could I get a form which is located within an iFrame to open up in a new tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, iframe

I'm having trouble with a page that has an iFrame. The page displayed within the iFrame is basically a form. On submit, it's supposed to open up a "thank you" page, but currently it does so WITHIN the bounds of the iFrame (and it's supposed to do so, I get that). Would it be possible to have the "thank you" page pop up in a new tab altogether?

I thought of using a `window.parent.open` JavaScript command on the onSubmit, but I'm not sure if this is the best way to go about it.

I'd found a similar query in Stack Overflow question *[Open in new window link in an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457288/open-in-new-window-link-in-iframe)*.

However, I wasn't able to tailor it to suit my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form element supports the `target` attribute.

```
<form action=foo target="_blank">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `target="_blank"`. Most browsers use that for new pages. Whatever the form is in the page, you can add `target="_blank"` before the end of the tag:

```
    <form action="..." method="...." target="_blank">
```