# iframe embeded website - href link not opening in external browser

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have an app and website. I want one of my website pages inside the app so I embedded it with iframe and it looks/works great except for one problem. All the href links inside my website open inside the app and cover the entire app (tabs and header). I would like the href links to open in safari/chrome externally. I've tried setting the href's target to _blank, _system, _parent, and _top. But they all still give the same behavior.

Can anyone give an idea that might help?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457288/open-in-new-window-link-in-an-iframe this is what you are looking for?

Comment: Hey thanks for your suggestions! Is window.open() what I would put on my in my website instead of href links? Or is it something I put in my app and somehow link it to iframe?